# Graphics.FillEllipse() giving an error after Task.Delay()

Tags: asynchronous, graphics, delay

This is the problematic part of the code:

```
private async void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
            int num;
            for (num = 0; num < seconds * tickspersecond - 1; num++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < starslenght; i++)
                {
                    x = Convert.ToDouble(readerx.ReadLine());
                    z = Convert.ToDouble(readerz.ReadLine());
                    x *= constant;
                    z *= constant;
                    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, (int)x + 960, (int)z + 540, 2, 2);
                }
                await Task.Delay(wait);
            }
            // brush.Dispose();
            // brush1.Dispose();
            // readerx.Dispose();
            // readerz.Dispose();
//brush, x, z , num, starslenght, tickspersecond, wait are defined before this piece of code and are correct.
        }
```

Every time the error occurs on the line with FillEllipse() exactly after the first completion of Task.Delay. The error is System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'
It is supposed to draw a set of points(very small circles) every `wait` milliseconds until the outer for loop ends.

Comment: What are the arguments for `FillEllipse` when it fails?

Comment: A Solidbrush that isnt disposed yet and four integers.

Comment: Yes, but are they valid values?

Comment: Yes, i checked with debug, otherwise it would crash instantly without reaching the line with Task.Delay

Comment: Your question says it fails the *second* time it's called. Are the values valid on the *second* call?

Comment: The error says they are not, but i dont see why given the code. I checked with debug and x and y values are being read properly.